# How to add another field in collections using mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I study mongodb and symfony. I succesfully creating a fields by following this documentation from symfony to mongodb [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html). 
If you can see documentation. They have these codes for connecting this documents to mongodb

```
/ src/Acme/StoreBundle/Document/Product.php
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="float")
     */
    protected $price;
}
```

Is this possible adding another field in Product like category, and an under the category there are another fields like
adding category_name and category_date? and how can I generate that document?

**Update:**
I want to create like these flow of fields in my mongodb collections

```
Product
  - id
  - name
  - price
  - category
      - category_name
      - category_date
```

Comment: You can add embeded document `category` with two fields `category_name`  and `category_date`.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb is a Nosql Database and Not Relational. It just accepts anything in key and value format. so may be you can add more fields like `category_name and category_date`. by adding the variable.

Comment: hi! I update my post. Is that possible the way I make my fields?

Comment: As i haven't explore mongodb much this will work for sure :

Comment: Product
  - id
  - name
  - price
  - category_name
  - category_date

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Embed Document
You can check it out here:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.1/reference/embedded-mapping.html